# PHP Array & for each

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a multi dimensional array in php, I would like to know how to get the "field name" of the value I'm returning in my foreach loop.

```
$_SESSION['filter']['dateCreation'] = 'ASC';
$_SESSION['filter']['client'] = 'test';

print_r($_SESSION['filter']);
foreach ($_SESSION['filter'] as $filter)
{
    // how do I echo the name of the field here? Eg. dateCreation
    echo $filter;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['filter'] as $keyname => $filter)
echo "$keyname value is $filter\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['filter'] as $key => $value) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['filter'] as $field_name=>$filter)
{
    echo $field_name, $filter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( $array as $key => value)
{
    ...
}
```

[Php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).